# How do I assign an on click listener to a game object that is created at runtime in Unity using C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I created a Quad. I assigned this script to the Quad that contains an array of Game Objects:

```
public class ShapeGrid : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject[] shapes;

    void Start(){
        GameObject[,] shapeGrid = new GameObject[3,3];
        StartCoroutine(UpdateGrid());
    }

    IEnumerator UpdateGrid(){
        while (true) {
            SetGrid ();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
        }
    }

    void SetGrid(){
        int col = 3, row = 3;
        for (int y = 0; y < row; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < col; x++) {
                int shapeId = (int)Random.Range (0, 4.9999f);
                GameObject shape = Instantiate (shapes[shapeId]);
                Vector3 pos = shapes [shapeId].transform.position;
                pos.x = (float)x*3;
                pos.y = (float)y*3;
                shapes [shapeId].transform.position = pos;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I cloned those Game Objects so that they appear on a grid like this:

[image]

When the user clicks an object, it should disappear. What I did was place this script on every element in my array of Game Objects:

```
public class ShapeBehavior : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update(){
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

But what happens is when I click on an object to destroy it, every clone of that object will be destroyed. I want only the specific clone to be destroyed, not everything. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on your Input call, "Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)" is true in every script when you click the button on mouse, no matter the position of mouse. Attach any kind of collider to gameObject and set it up and put the script with OnMouseDown() method, look here for more info : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

You can also use raycasting but that's more advanced way of solving this.

Also replace this.gameObject with just gameObject.

Comment: It worked! Thank you. But it resulted to another error. MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.

Comment: From what script exactly are you getting that?

Comment: The script that I assigned to the Quad. It's from this line:  GameObject shape = Instantiate (shapes[shapeId]);

Comment: Nevermind. I fixed it by adding the script to the cloned objects at run time, instead of adding them to the original objects before run time by using this code. shape.AddComponent<ShapeBehavior>(); But then the problem is, sometimes the OnMouseDown() method executes, sometimes it doesn't. And I can't figure out when it does, and when it doesn't.

Comment: No point in doing that before run time, after run time check if the script is successfuly attached to it in inspector, check for colliders too.

Comment: Nevermind. I got it to work already. It was because I did not set all parameters of Vector3 pos. Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad it works, accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I mixed you up with another post I was answering :D